# Using placeholder ? in Go mySql query for anything other than int

Tags: mysql, go

I've already setup and pinged my mysql database connection. It is working and I can return rows using both db.Query and by preparing a query first. I can use the placeholder *?* to then specify an id. Is it possible to use the ? as a placeholder for a column name? In the example here I am trying to return all rows from column *firstName* in table *persons*.

```
qry, err := db.Prepare("SELECT ? FROM persons")
if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
defer qry.Close()
rows, err :=qry.Query("firstName")
if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
defer rows.Close()
```

I get the following error:
*Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
 syntax to use near '?' at line 1*

Comment: Placeholders are for data only, you can't use them for identifiers (table names, column names, etc.). If you feel that you need to do that you're very likely doing it wrong.

Comment: @Peter I was just testing the package out and thought I'd create a very basic query that could be extended with placeholders to more efficiently test multiple scenarios. Considering that the Prepare() and Query() solution is meant to guard against injection, this restriction makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use placeholders for identifiers (such as table and column names), placeholders are for *values*. You can think of identifiers as being similar to variable or function names in Go so being able to use placeholders for identifiers would be akin to having an `eval` as in various scripting languages.

This reduces you to using `fmt.Sprintf` and similar string operations for building the SQL when you don't know the identifiers until runtime:

```
col := "firstName"
sql := fmt.Sprintf("select %s from persons", col)
```

but this opens you up to SQL injection and quoting problems so you'd want some sort of whitelist:

```
quotedColumns := map[string]string{
    "firstName": "`firstName`",
    "lastName": "`lastName`",
    ...
}

quoted, ok := quotedColumns[columnName]
if !ok {
    // Do something with the error here and run away...
}
sql := fmt.Sprintf("select %s from persons", quoted)
```

Note that I've included the MySQL backtick quoting in the map's values. There's nothing in the standard interface for quoting/escaping an identifier so you have to do it yourself. If you're already writing the whitelist map by hand then you may as well include the quoting by hand too; otherwise you could write your own quoting function for identifiers by reading the MySQL documentation on quoting and doing a couple (hopefully) simple string operations.

Comment: I figured that was the case as I was able to use Exec() to insert strings into a sql string with VALUES(?), but not change the identifiers. The Sprintf() is an interesting end run around the restriction I had not thought of.

Comment: @spynovel, do take care to only stitch string constants together with sprints, though. It's easy to go from there to not using parameters anymore.